# InnoDB: very bad performance on INSERT/UPDATE

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, optimization

Lately I have really big problems with INSERTs and UPDATEs. On my website 80% of all queries are SELECTs but in query slow log there are only INSERTs and UPDATEs. My dedicated server has 32GB RAM, Core i7 but no SSD drive.

mysqltuner says:

```
-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.14
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 203M (Tables: 23)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 1G (Tables: 96)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 5M (Tables: 4)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 37

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 10h 54m 18s (3M q [93.602 qps], 131K conn, TX: 22B, RX: 713M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 83% / 17%
[--] Total buffers: 4.0G global + 1.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 4.2G (12% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (535/3M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 4% (7/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/98.7M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.7% (10M cached / 28K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 66.2% (1M cached / 2M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 290517
[!!] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 16% (43K temp sorts / 261K sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 17% (20K on disk / 119K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (7 created / 131K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 26% (413 open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (125/100K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (2M immediate / 2M locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 1.3G/3.0G

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 32M)
    sort_buffer_size (> 256K)
    read_rnd_buffer_size (> 256K)
```

I already tried to optimize MySQL configuration but it didn't help so much.
my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3GB
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=16M
innodb_autoextend_increment = 128M
innodb_log_file_size = 500M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 750M

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 32M
query_cache_size  = 32M

tmp_table_size = 220M
max_heap_table_size = 220M

sql_mode=
event-scheduler=1
long_query_time=2
```

Most of queries on my slow query log are really simple. Tables are medium so that's wired. However most problematic query is INSERT to table that has ~900k records (InnoDB):

```
CREATE TABLE `topic_marking` (
    `topic_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `user_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `forum_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `mark_time` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `topic_id_2` (`topic_id`, `user_id`),
    INDEX `forum_id` (`forum_id`),
    INDEX `topic_id` (`topic_id`),
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `topic_marking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_id`) REFERENCES `topic` (`topic_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `topic_marking_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `topic_marking_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`forum_id`) REFERENCES `forum` (`forum_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

As you can see there is a lot of indexes and foregin keys. I thought that might be a problem so I decieded to remove all foreign keys and leave only two indexes (topic_id_2 and forum_id). Well, that helped a little bit but didn't eliminate a problem.

What else can I do to improve perfomance except buying additional SDD drive?

I have ~50 queries/sec.
Profiling simple UPDATE query gives results like that:

```
starting
0.000028
checking permissions
0.000004
Opening tables
0.000017
init
0.000014
System lock
0.000026
updating
0.000033
end
0.000003
Waiting for query cache lock
0.000002
end
0.000066
query end
7.456112
closing tables
0.000019
freeing items
0.000013
logging slow query
0.000054
cleaning up
0.000011
```

So `query_end` takes like 7 seconds! What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

THis is possibly tx flushing.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937443/query-end-step-very-long-at-random-times for something similar.

There, adding

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0

helped.

If you run a typical 7200RPM large but slow disc, your IOPS budget is VERY limited. Your only real steps here are lying (like up - not commiting, or having the disc physically in write back mode, confirming a write before it happens) or getting more IOPS (which is where SSD really shine - you can easily get a SSD with 60.000 IOPS - that is 400 times the budget.

Lying is not advisable unless you have batteries in place to cover power failures - possibly with a raid controller that has a battery on top, too. If that is an invetment, a SSD is the absolutely most cost effective way to do things.

You most liekly just kille the IO budget. SOmeone with more linux exerperience can step in and tell you how to measure that - i think there is a command iotop that can do that.

Comment: Well, turned out that one of the HDD is corrupted. I disabled it and everything works just fine